# Super User is planning to add Android to our migration paths: any feedback?

Tags: discussion, migration, close-reasons

Greetings, Androids! I am a moderator over on Super User, and we're talking about [adding Android Enthusiasts to our default migration paths](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4435/request-to-add-android-enthusiasts-to-the-default-list-of-migration-targets) (available to 3K+ users). Right now, when there's an Android question on Super User, it can only be migrated manually by a moderator.

Migration statistics on SU show that Android is the 4th most common migration target from Super User. We hardly ever migrate to Gaming, which is currently occupying the last slot in our default migration options. We would like to replace that with Android, since it would allow our high-rep users to migrate questions here without needing moderator intervention. This would increase the number of android-related questions which get actual answers instead of just being closed, and lower the burden on us moderators.

Before making the switch, we'd like to make sure that's OK with the moderators and users over here. Have you seen any problems with incoming android-related questions from Super User? Are there any reservations about opening this up as a migration path?

We have pretty unanimous agreement among SU users to go ahead and implement this, but thought we should double check with you first, just to make sure. If everybody on this side is down with it, we'll go ahead and switch it out!

Thanks! — nhinkle♦, SU moderator

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wouldn't mind seeing some *good* Android questions migrated from SU. `$DEITY` knows we have our own fair share of not-so-good questions. There have been a few migrated questions from SU recently, if memory serves, and they were mostly okay.

Some things to keep in mind:

- Developer questions are explicitly off-topic, so don't bother.
- We have commonly duplicated questions about updates and rooting, so expect such questions to be promptly closed when migrated:

  - [How do I root my device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-device)
  - [I've rooted my phone. Now what? What do I gain from rooting?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1/ive-rooted-my-phone-now-what-what-do-i-gain-from-rooting)
  - [When will my phone get the Android 2.3 update (Gingerbread)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2695/when-will-my-phone-get-the-android-2-3-update-gingerbread)
  - [When will my device get the Android 4.0 update (Ice Cream Sandwich)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14766/when-will-my-device-get-the-android-4-0-update-ice-cream-sandwich)
- Please, *please*, **please** don't migrate questions just to get rid of them (i.e. poorly written, shopping recommendations, or of the "Why doesn't my X work?", "Best app to do Y" variety with little additional information). Better close them outright, because we will anyway<sup>1</sup>.

**Disclaimer:** This is only opinion of my own as a user here and I expect Android moderators would have something to say as well.

<sup>1</sup> This is mostly valid for questions asked by first-time SE users. It's usually hard to pry out the necessary information to answer the question, and those can linger for ages unanswered. Experienced SE users show greater cooperation, even if their questions lack important details.

Comment: Of course, as Jeff always says - **don't migrate crap!** We get our fair share of crap migrations (lookin' at you, Stack Overflow), so of course we'll do our best not to send you outright _bad_ questions. If we go through with this, I'll put an update on our blog about the change and reminding people what does and doesn't belong on Android. Thanks for your insights!

Comment: @nhinkle Mind making sure the other mods get that memo? We just got a pretty bad one: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/20839/1465

Comment: @MatthewRead: I take full responsibility, it was completely my fault on that migration, I apologize.

Comment: @studiohack No worries, sometimes it's hard when you have a bunch of close-voters telling you where it belongs. Topic seems to take precedence over quality when it comes to close voters, unfortunately!

Comment: @MatthewRead thanks for the understanding... Not sure what I was thinking at the time... Cheers! :)

Answer (score 6):

That's fine with me. I've been trolling at Super User in the android tag fairly regularly to find migration candidates. I probably won't have to do it is much any more.

For what it's worth, the rejection rate for questions migrated here from Super User in the last 90 days is 11%.

Answer (score 3):

This if fine by me. [Martin covers all the points](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/a/858/10) I was going to say. Pass on over the good questions. :)